# Discord.js bot sending two memes from different reddits

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So basically, I'm trying to get my discord bot to send a meme from r/marvelmemes, as the bot is for a MCU themed server. I followed a tutorial to create my code, and in the tutorial, the coder used r/memes. I only changed one thing. I changed this line:

```
got('https://www.reddit.com/r/memes/random/.json').then(response => {
```

Into this:

```
got('https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelmemes/random/.json').then(response => {
```

That's all I changed from the original tutorial. When I try to run the bot, it does in fact send a meme from r/marvelmemes. However, it also sends a meme from r/memes. It sends two memes. How do I make it so that it only sends one meme from r/marvelmemes? Here's the full code.

```
const got = require ('got');
module.exports = {
    name: 'meme',
    description: "send a meme",
    execute(message, args, Discord) {
        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        got('https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelmemes/random/.json').then(response => {
            let content = JSON.parse(response.body);
            let permalink = content[0].data.children[0].data.permalink;
            let memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            let memeImage = content[0].data.children[0].data.url;
            let memeTitle = content[0].data.children[0].data.title;
            let memeUpvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.ups;
            let memeDownvotes = content[0].data.children[0].data.downs;
            let memeNumComments = content[0].data.children[0].data.num_comments;
            embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`)
            embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`)
            embed.setImage(memeImage)
            embed.setColor('RANDOM')
            embed.setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeDownvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`)
            message.channel.send(embed);
        })
    }
}
```

I use a basic command handler, and here's what it looks like if it helps:

```
client.on('message', message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if (command == 'meme') {
        client.commands.get('meme').execute(message, args, Discord);
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me; the code above only sends one meme, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have a second bot running because of multiple terminals.

If you have Visual Studio Code, you can see them here:
[image: vsc]
Here you are able to delete terminals (red box)